# C_GetSlotList Failing when called from IIS but not from IIS express

Tags: iis, cryptography, pkcs#11

So I have this c# webservice that eventuallly calls C_GetSlotList() method from the German Elster toolkit (Eric) thru some smartcard usb driver placed in system32 folder.
I have a smartcard in the computer server. When I host my service in IIS Express everything works fine, however in IIS it doesn't. What could be the problem? Does something block IIS from accessing the driver? I made sure that the identity of the application pool I'm using has admin rights.
I'm using Windows 7 professional and this is the kind of log I am getting:

```
2016-10-18 15:16:58,144560  INFO: esigner       cryptokiVersion = 02.14
2016-10-18 15:16:58,144560  INFO: esigner        manufacturerID = A.E.T. Europe B.V.              
2016-10-18 15:17:01,244870 ERROR: esigner       error calling C_GetSlotList()
2016-10-18 15:17:01,244870 ERROR: esigner                    rv = 00000006
2016-10-18 15:17:01,244870 ERROR: esigner           ulSlotCount = 0
2016-10-18 15:17:01,244870 ERROR: esigner       pkcs11_init() failed
2016-10-18 15:17:01,245870  INFO: esigner  ENGINE_set_default_RSA(0436CC30) = returned 0
2016-10-18 15:17:01,245870  INFO: esigner       esiclGetToken() = end critical section
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing IIS application pool identity to LocalService usually helps. Don't ask me why :)

Comment: you earned yourself a beer, man and my boss would probably kiss your feet:). it worked:D

Comment: will do, I'll only test it on the other computers, too.

Comment: Don't Ask me why :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to access the current user certificate store, changing the IIS Application Pool will solve one problem but introduce another.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72857294/18406310).