# pkcs11 interop GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent); returns empty list

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

I am using pkcs11 interop library to list available devices like this

```
using (Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11(_libraryPath, AppType.SingleThreaded))
{
    List<Slot> slots =  pkcs11.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent);
    //using slots
}
```

it works fine but when i use same code in web application or run it loop i am getting slots count as 0 even if device is connected.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113586/c-getslotlist-failing-when-called-from-iis-but-not-from-iis-express

Comment: Thanks, @jariq my web service is not on IIS, It is a self-host web-API  running as windows service with local system privilege which has more rights than local service

Answer (score 0):

What is the PKCS#11 library? Does it happen to be for a network-based device or one what has a corresponding service on the box? I suspect you do not have permissions to LPC/RPC to its corresponding server.