# How to access client side USB Token based Digital Signing Certificate in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2012, digital-signature

I have developed an MVC Application, which uses USB Token Digital Signature Certificate. When I run the application from Visual Studio, it works fine. But when I publish it on IIS it doesn't detect USB Token. Do I need to make changes/configuration in IIS server?

Comment: Take a look at my [older answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40114688/3325704).